# Escaping Particular Special Characters

Tags: python, django, special-characters

I have a string like: `'SEBASTIÁN'`, and when I save this in the db, it saves as encoded. While trying to show it in frontend through python code it's throwing an error.

```
In [1]: p = "SEBASTIÁN"

In [2]: p
Out[2]: 'SEBASTI\xc3\x81N'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5):

Use unicode strings with django.

```
u"SEBASTIÁN"
↑
```

Please read this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/unicode/

Comment: Its still the same for me. In [5]: p = u"AGUADILLA-ISABELA-SAN SEBASTIÁN"

In [6]: p
Out[6]: u'AGUADILLA-ISABELA-SAN SEBASTI\xc1N'
Is there any python inbuilt method using which we can escape.

Comment: Then post the error and your actual code. `\xc1` is `Á`. Try `print p`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know django, but this works in python 3:

`>>> b'SEBASTI\xc3\x81N'.decode("utf-8", "strict")

'SEBASTIÁN'`

Comment: Its not about django, I need a python function which can parse/decode it. I am using python 2.6

Answer (score 0):

You should be saving this as a unicode string

```
>>>p = u"SEBASTIÁN"
>>> print p
SEBASTIÁN
```